# Tre Flip (360 flip) on a skateboard

Tags: technique, skateboarding

I am currently trying to perform a 360 flip on a skateboard and I can get as close as varial Kickflip (180 degrees as appose to 360 degrees shuv with flip) I would like to know how I ensure that the board shuvs 360 degrees as well as staying under my feet for the full Tre Flip. Any ideas? hints? tips?
Thanks :)

Ive been hard at work on this trick lately but ive noticed as soon as I get the full flip I cannot get the 360 degree shuv and when I get the 3' shuv I cannot get the flip... its rather annoying how can I get the board to flip and spin at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, as you know, the Tre Flip consists of using your back foot to scoop and flip while your front foot coordinates the slide off of the board in the right position. So if your back foot isn't kicking horizontally enough, you will not get the full 360 rotation. To get the full rotation, try kicking like you would kick off to push a scooter forward. If you aren't getting enough flip, then the problem could be your front slide foot or the direction of your back foot's kick on the board. You should be kicking slightly downwards and backwards with your back foot. Your foot's position on the back of the board should be almost like grabbing the edge that starts the curve of the board closest to your toe. This should give you more leverage on the down force of your kick and enough friction on the kickback. The front sliding foot should be angled to the outside of the board about 45 degrees and should slide along that plane. This will create the pressure differential on the board that will flip the board without stopping the turn. The video I'm including as a link below is really good for showing the motion of the front and back feet, as well as the position of your feet for the ideal, not so sketchy, Tre Flip.
Hope this helps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuOcEBS8Qfk

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Casey mentioned, I think that jumping slightly in front of you helps. I find the board doesn't always land where you started - it's normally in front of you by about a half foot.
You'll notice that those who land it often jump forward in anticipation.. at least a little bit.

Comment: Yes, this is the main contribution for increasing rotational potential. Also, if the front foot moves a little farther back, towards the back foot, it helps reduce the moment of angle required to rotate the board as well.